# Monaco editor in react stop highlighting from working when using a delta decoration

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor

I edit monaco lines with a delta decoration like so:

```
    range: new Range(3,1,5,1000),
    options: {
      isWholeLine: true,
      className: css(styles.error),
    },
```

The class:

```
  error: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
  },
```

but what ends up happening is the user highlighting on those lines no longer works.

I've tried using the selectors in css such as `::selection` within the error class, but that didn't seem to do anything. This is using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@monaco-editor/react.

I haven't found a solution and a similar question was asked 7 years ago for hover but no answer that one as well.

Comment: Look at the generated HTML. Which CSS class is assigned to the line you wanna show highlighted? Maybe the delta decoration overrides the line highlight?